# nano: do you know if is there any way to open the last edited file?

Tags: nano

Im just starting with `nano`, and I'm wondering if is there any way to open the last edited file in `nano` after close and open it again?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about the portability, I tested it on my zsh shell.
This opens the last instance of nano:

```
eval $(fc -l 100 | cut -c 8- | grep -v grep | grep "[n]ano" | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: where should I write it?